# Why can't my Ruby module method access my module class variable?

Tags: ruby, module

In the code below:

```
module UserInterface

    @main_menu_options = { 1 => "Display Task List", 2 => "Add New Task", 3 => "Edit A Task", 4 => "Delete A Task", "Q" => "Quit" }

    def main_menu(string="")
        @main_menu_options.each_value { |v| puts v }
        if @main_menu_options == nil then puts "NOTHING THERE" end
    end

end
```

I've created a module variable and put a standard Ruby hash inside it.

But the first line of the main_menu method can't display the values.

When I comment out the first line of that method, the second line always displays "NOTHING THERE", which tells me that the method thinks the class variable contains nil.

I also tried recreating that exact same hash in the method body, and that line of code could display its values perfectly fine, so I don't see how it can be the statement in the method. I think the problem must be the module class variable.

Why does that module method think there's nothing in my @main_menu_options module class variable when it clearly has something in it?

Comment: I assume you invoked `main_menu` from an instance of a class that included that module. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I know what I need to do now. I need to make that module variable a constant so that it can be accessed at the module level and by anything that includes that module.

Comment: You could retrieve (or set) the module instance variable directly:  `module M; @m = 99; end; M.instance_variable_get("@a") #=> 99` (or `..._get(:@a)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `@main_menu_options` is not the same as the `@main_menu_options` referenced in the mixin method. The second method operates in the context of whatever called `include`.

If you want these both on the same page you'll need to redefine that method to be in the same scope:

```
module UserInterface
  @main_menu_options = {
    1 => "Display Task List",
    2 => "Add New Task",
    3 => "Edit A Task",
    4 => "Delete A Task",
    "Q" => "Quit"
  }

  # Module-level method has access to module-level defined variables
  def self.main_menu(string = "")
    @main_menu_options.each_value { |v| puts v }

    if @main_menu_options == nil then puts "NOTHING THERE" end
  end
end
```

This misses the bigger problem. Since those options never change you really should be defining this as a constant:

```
module UserInterface
  MAIN_MENU_OPTIONS = {
    1 => "Display Task List",
    2 => "Add New Task",
    3 => "Edit A Task",
    4 => "Delete A Task",
    "Q" => "Quit"
  }

  def main_menu(string = "")
    MAIN_MENU_OPTIONS.each_value { |v| puts v }

    if MAIN_MENU_OPTIONS == nil then puts "NOTHING THERE" end
  end
end
```

You'll need to fix your `if` since that's not really functional code. When writing Ruby try to avoid one-liners like that, skip the `then` to avoid clutter.

Comment: I don't see the point of the last line in `def main_menu`. If `MAIN_MENU_OPTIONS` is nill then the line above would have raised a NoMethodError.

Comment: Oh never mind I see you just copied this from the question

Comment: Thank you very much @tadman.  And thanks for your advice about the if statement.  So just to be clear, if I make that variable a constant, I don't need to add "self." before the method name?

Comment: Constants are available to both the module level context and the mixin level at the same time, they're more "universal" that way, so yes. Same principle applies in a class.